# C# Get all nodes in xml document but ignoring nested nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml document where i need to iterate over all nodes that are direct descendants of the parent.

For example i have the following xml document

```
<root>
  <node1>val1</node1>
  <node2>val2</node2>
  <nodes>
    <nestedNode>nestedvalue</nestedNode>
  </nodes>
</root>
```

I have the following code which gets me all the elements:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*");
```

This returns node1, node2, and nestedNode. What i want is only node1 and node2 and to ignore any nested values.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select elements that are children of the root element you would use the xpath:

```
/root/*
```

or in general:

```
/*/*
```

You should not traverse the all descendants here (`//...`) as that will go through *all* elements in the document. You would have to add additional filtering which would make the query unnecessarily complicated:

```
//*[parent::*[not(parent::*)]]
```

However, you want to filter out elements that do not have other child elements so you need to add the condition `not(*)`:

```
/*/*[not(*)]
```

Comment: Fantastic!! That worked. Will accept answer when time allows.